# C++ enumeration copy constructor and assignment operator

Tags: c++, enumeration, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

I just found out that enumerations have default constructors and assignment operators in C++. Does anyone have an example of an enumeration with non-defaults copy constructor and assignment operator ?

Answer (score 0):

`enum` are just `int`s, that's why they will always have "assignment operator".

By the standard **by default**, the first element of an `enum` always has `0` as value, and all other elements, after the first one, are "previous_value + 1".

<sub>You can change the value of the first element, of course. Actually, you can give values for each "member" of the enum.

Thanks to @Konrad Rudolph for the comment. I just didn't mention "by default" at the beginning, as we were talking about "default construction".</sub>

So no, there are no `enum`s without "assignment operator" and "default/copy constructor".

Comment: You mean, that `first` will be `1`, if it's not explicitly said, or that you may change the value of `first`?

Comment: That you may change it. It’s not necessarily 0.

Comment: You can make the first element have any value you like, it's NOT always 0.

Comment: As I don't have my copy of the spec handy: `enum` types need to be able to store all `or` combinations of values -- is the empty combination also included in that set?

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph - Well, I was talking about "by default", as here, we're talking about "default constructor". But OK, point taken, I'll add this.

Comment: @SimonRichter - I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @SimonRichter `enum` types are required to be able to store *all* values of the underlying type, not just combinations. For example `enum { a = 100 }` will have at least 2^CHAR_BIT values, which is usually 256. It just happens that only one of them is named.

Answer (score 0):

Enumerators behave much like integral types except for fewer implicit conversions. I can't think of a case where there would be non-default copy constructor or assignment operators for an enumeration (unless you wrapped it in a class).

Comment: But can I define my own copy constructor and assignment operator?

Comment: I just saw the following example in Java, and wonder if I can do the same in C++

Comment: enum Apple {  
  A(10),   B(9), C(12), D(15), E(8);

  private int price; // price of each apple 

  // Constructor 
  Apple(int p) {
    price = p;
  }

  int getPrice() {
    return price;
  }
}`

Comment: @Andre - In C++ the copy constructor and assignment operator must be members of a class/struct/union. Not possible for enums.